# Getting subsection to list in table of contents in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I made a table of contents using `\tableofcontents` Each section is made using `\section` yet when I do `\subsection` it is not listed in the table. How do I get it to list there? Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Which document class are you using? I just tested it for `article`, and it works fine. In any case, try using this in the preamble:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

Increase `2` if you want to list `subsubsection`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked for me. I just put this line with {3} before \tableofcontents.

Answer (score 5):

Add:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
```

to the preamble.

See: http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/linux-unix/latex-setting-table-of-contents-toc-depth

Answer (score 0):

@WhirlWind and @Steve_Tjoa got it and helped me too! One thing though, whatever you set the tocdepth counter to, you may also want to set the secnumdepth.

so i used

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
```

as suggested by @Whirlwind but then the subsubsection in my Table of Contents wasn't numbered. so I added the following to get it to work (thanks to the following link where i found the answer http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2351#p9197 )

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```